# How to migrate usage of JpaTemplate from Spring 3.2 to 4.1.4?

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-4

We currently have Spring 3.2.9.RELEASE configured and running (for a couples of years) and need to migrate to 4.1.4.RELEASE. We have an abstract DAO class that extends `org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.JpaDaoSupport` as well as other references to:

- `org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaCallback`
- `org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTemplate`

I've seen that `JpaDaoSupport` has been removed in Spring 4. I've removed references to the Jpa* classes and replaced with

```
@PersistenceContext 
protected EntityManager theEntityManager;
```

and for method references in our DAO (like `findByNamedParams()`) found in `JpaDaoSupport`, and copied into our DAO.

After the above changes, we are able to compile our code but when it comes to running our JUnit tests, there is a reference in our `applicationContext-test.xml` of

```
<bean id="jpaTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTemplate">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="abstractDAO" abstract="true" class="my.company.package.AbstractDAO">
    <property name="jpaTemplate" ref="jpaTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="genericDAO" parent="abstractDAO" class="my.company.package.GenericDAO" />
<bean id="securityDAO" parent="abstractDAO" class="my.company.package.SecurityDAOImpl" />
```

Basically the error is there is no class reference of `org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTemplate`. How do we replace this `JpaTemplate` configuration for Spring 4.1.4?

Note that I'm picking this code up and wasn't the one who initially configured the system. Also I'm pretty new to Spring and its configuration setup.

Answer (score 3):

1. Make sure `AbstractDAO` is migrated to the `EntityManager` API and uses `@PersistenceContext` on an injection point (a setter usually).
2. Enable annotation configuration using `<context:annotation-config />` or configure a `PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` to enable the injection of the `EntityManager` into the DAOs. You can get rid of the bean definition for `AbstractDAO` entirely. Note, that if you have `<context:component-scan />` activated somewhere, this should already work out of the box.

PS: You might wanna consider to upgrade to Spring 4.2 right away if you're migrating anyway. If that's not an option, please go with the latest Spring 4.1 version (4.1.7 at the time of writing).

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying. Here are the changes:The jpaTemplate is removed in the above reference. The abstractDAO above does not have property reference. We are able to get past the junit test. During our WL 12c startup, we're now getting the following exception: Caused By: java.lang.ClassCastException: net.sf.ehcache.store.compound.ReadWriteSerializationCopyStrategy cannot be cast to net.sf.ehcache.store.compound.ReadWriteCopyStrategy
    There are other springframework exceptions before this one but i can't paste them here due to lack of space.

Comment: The exception of the one here is Caused By: java.lang.RuntimeException: ReadWriteSerializationCopyStrategy doesn't implement net.sf.ehcache.store.compound.CopyStrategy