# Spring 4 recommended replacement of JpaTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, entitymanager, spring-4

I have a legacy project which was using Spring 3.0.x and made use of the `JpaTemplate` implementation provided by Spring.

However, after upgrading to Spring 4.0.x I learned that `JpaTemplate` was deprecated as of Spring 3.2

I have seen suggestions to simply refactor out the use of `JpaTemplate` with `EntityManager`.

However, replacing `JpaTemplate` with `EntityManager` is not sufficient as I discovered this project was wrapping the `JpaTemplate` calls in a `JpaCallback`, which in turn used entitymanager. I imagine the reason callbacks were used was to allow these DAO calls to be ran asynchronously.

Are there any suggested recommendations on how to refactor applications which make use of JpaTemplate and the JpaCallback class when upgrading to Spring 4?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31925138/how-to-migrate-usage-of-jpatemplate-from-spring-3-2-to-4-1-4

Comment: If it is a `JpaCallback` it is quite easy to replace that with an entity manager, just re move the wrapping code. The `JpaCallback` doesn't wrap the template it is the other way around. One thing you might now find is that you have an issue with transactions, and that is basically a sign of having a wrong transaction setup in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Additionally to replacing `JPATemplate`, you should enable annotation configuration using `<context:annotation-config />` or configure a `PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` to enable the injection of the `EntityManager` into the DAOs.
If you have `<context:component-scan />` activated, you should be fine to use all the features as it was before migration.