# How to know what packages were deprecated in Spring 4.3.19?

Tags: spring

Recently we upgrade our spring version from 3.2.14 to 4.3.19.
After upgrading, Java Module is not able to detect these packages:

```
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaCallback;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTemplate;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.JpaDaoSupport;
```

Were these packages depreciated for the newer version of spring 4.3.19?

Didn't get much help from Spring Documentation.

Comment: Probably a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/35121155/1531971

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring 4 recommended replacement of JpaTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35121155/spring-4-recommended-replacement-of-jpatemplate)